# Help fixed point math to initialize a bonding curve

Tags: solidity, bonding-curves

I'm having difficulty computing an initial tokenSupply parameter in Solidity, one of two required parameters to initialize a Bancor-style bonding curve contract.

Formula:

```
P = sent Ether in Wei

R = reserve ratio

M = Slope

tokenSupply = (P/(R*M))^R
```

Suppose:

```
P = 1 * 10^18

R = .333333

M = .0025

N = Scaling Factor =  1/1,000,000
```

This seems fine:

```
tokenSupply = 1*10^18 / ((N)333,333 * (N)2500) * N
```

Now:

```
tokenSupply = ( 1*10^18 / (N)833 )^R
```

But #1:

Can I divide the unscaled wei by the scaled product (N)833 and assume the quotient has the same scaling factor N?

.#2:

How on earth do I raise this quotient to R? (Assuming R's initial Scaling Factor, 333,333 is out of the question) And how do I know what the scaling factor would be of the result `tokenSupply`? (I don't know how to handle scaled exponents).  Thanks

*I am using SafeMath to handle overflows*

Sources: 
https://blog.relevant.community/bonding-curves-in-depth-intuition-parametrization-d3905a681e0a
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic

Answer (score 2):

> Can I divide the unscaled wei by the scaled product (833) and assume the quotient is the same scaling factor of the scaled product?

The question is not very clear to me, but `tokenSupply = 1*10^18 / ((N)333,333 * (N)2500) * N` seems wrong, as you are scaling the denominator by `N*N` but multiplying the result only by `N`.

If you're doing it off-chain, then there's no need for a scaling-factor whatsoever, and you can simply calculate `P/(R*M)`.

If you're doing it on-chain, then you should multiply the result by `N*N` instead of by `N`. Also, please note that you're much better off doing it **before** you divide and not after.

To summarize this, you should do: `P*N*N/(R*N*M*N)`.

P.S.: In your numeric example, you can use a smaller value of `N` (100K instead of 1M).

> How on earth do I raise this quotient to R?

The reserve-ratio must be a value between 0 and 1.

If you're doing it off-chain, then simply raise to the power of `R`.

If you're doing it on-chain, then you can use [Bancor's power function](https://github.com/bancorprotocol/contracts/blob/master/solidity/contracts/converter/BancorFormula.sol), which takes the exponent as a tuple of numerator and denominator, and pass to it your `R` as [333333, 1000000].

**UPDATE:**

If you are doing everything on-chain, then I recommend that you use Bancor's `power` function "all the way through":

```
uint256 result;
uint8 precision;
uint256 baseN = P.mul(10000000000);
uint256 baseD = R*M scaled by 10000000000
uint256 expN = R scaled by 1000000
uint256 expD = 1000000
(result, precision) = power(baseN, baseD, expN, expD);
```

At this point, the integer value of `supply` can be calculated using `result >> precision`.

Comment: "tokenSupply = 1*10^18 / ((N)333,333 * (N)2500) * N seems wrong, as you are scaling the denominator by N*N but multiplying the result only by N" Rationale(wiki source): "If the two operands belong to the same fixed-point type, and the result is also to be represented in that type, then the product of the two integers must be explicitly multiplied by the common scaling factor" This brings the product from the intermediate scaling factor back to the original, no? 
N = 1/1,000,000
(N)X * (N)Y = N^2(XY) so 
N^2(XY) * N = (N)XY

Comment: @Zach_is_my_name: As in your original question, I find your descrition very hard to understand. In short, since you use `N` twice in the denominator, you should use it twice in the numerator. However, I'm not sure how you have `R` and `M` represented to begin with. Obviously, they're not given to you as `0.333333` and `0.0025`, but as a pair of numerators and a pair of denominators... Or perhaps as a pair of numerators and a single denominator used for both. If that is indeed the case, and that denominator is `N`, then just make sure to multiply `P` by `N*N` instead of just by `N`.

Comment: This is building a constructor feeding arguments to Bancor's original BancorFormula.sol which takes connectorWeight (R) as a fraction in ppm hence 333333. I've assigned Slope (M) the same scaling factor.  I'll look at and compare the operations you're proposing to the one's I'm using (taken from the source I cited). But even more helpful perhaps something you alluded to, doing the tokenSupply calculation off chain and seeing if the curve behaves as expected.  Again this is to solve the problem of bootstapping a bonding curve with initial poolBalance (msg.value) and tokenSupply (pre-calculated)

Answer (score 0):

Solidity does not support fractional math out of the box, so you need either to use some sort of library, or to implement fractions yourself.  I would recommend using [ABDKMathQuad](https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMathQuad.md) library for your task.  Here is how the code may look like:

```solidity
function calculateBancorTotalSupply (
  uint etherAmount,
  uint reserveRatio,
  uint slope,
  uint scale)
public pure returns (uint) {
  bytes16 scaleQuad = ABDKMathQuad.fromUInt (scale);

  bytes16 reserveRatioQuad = ABDKMathQuad.div (
    ABDKMathQuad.fromUInt (reserveRatio),
    scaleQuad);

  bytes16 slopeQuad = ABDKMathQuad.div (
    ABDKMathQuad.fromUInt (slope),
    scaleQuad);

  return ABDKMathQuad.toUInt (
    ABDKMathQuad.pow_2 (
      ABDKMathQuad.mul (
        ABDKMathQuad.log_2 (
          ABDKMathQuad.div (
            ABDKMathQuad.fromUInt (etherAmount),
            ABDKMathQuad.mul (reserveRatioQuad, slopeQuad))),
        reserveRatioQuad)));
}
```

For

```
etherAmount = 1000000000000000000
reserveRatio = 333333
slope = 2500
scale = 1000000
```

This code gives me `10626417` which is the same as [Google returns for the same data](https://www.google.com/search?q=1e18%2F(0.333333*0.0025))%5E0.333333&rlz=1C1GGRV_enDE757DE758&oq=1e18%2F(0.333333*0.0025))%5E0.333333).  The function consumes `26876` gas (Solidity 0.5.14 with enabled optimizations).

Bancor's `power` solution, [suggested by](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/66199/4955) [goodvibration](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/16043/goodvibration), returned `10625630` spending `37181` gas (Solidity 0.4.26 with enabled optimizations).  So Bancor's solution seems to be somewhat less precise and more expensive, than ABDKMathQuad solution.

Here is the code I used to test Bancor's solution:

```solidity
function calculateBancorTotalSupply (
  uint etherAmount,
  uint reserveRatio,
  uint slope,
  uint scale)
public view returns (uint) {
  uint256 result;
  uint8 precision;
  uint256 baseN = etherAmount * scale * scale;
  uint256 baseD = reserveRatio * slope;
  uint256 expN = reserveRatio;
  uint256 expD = scale;
  (result, precision) = power(baseN, baseD, uint32 (expN), uint32 (expD));
  return result >> precision;
}
```